# Open/Close Door in coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't quite understand how to manage rotations in coroutines, I manage them via coroutines because every interactive object passes through a general interactive script, I tried like this but the desired effect is not what I was hoping for, I would like a simple smooth movement for opening and closing of the door, but with my script it only goes slow once, then you have to wait for the time for it to reset and then it goes slow again, if I repeatedly click the button to interact, the door closes/opens quickly.. could you help me?

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorsWithoutKey : MonoBehaviour
{
  
    public bool open = false;
   
    [SerializeField] private float smooth = 2.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float DoorOpenAngle = 90.0f;
    private Vector3 defaulRot;
    private Vector3 openRot;
    [SerializeField] public float lerpDuration = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        defaulRot = transform.eulerAngles;
        openRot = new Vector3(defaulRot.x, defaulRot.y + DoorOpenAngle, defaulRot.z);
    }


    public void NewOpenClosed()
    {
        open = !open;
        StartCoroutine(OpenDoor());
    }

    private IEnumerator OpenDoor()
    {
        float timeElapsed = 0;

        while (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
        {

            if (open)
            {
                gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(transform.eulerAngles, openRot, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
            }
            else
            {
                gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(transform.eulerAngles, defaulRot, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
            }
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;

        }        
    }
}
```

I would like the door to have a smooth movement

Comment: the more you click the faster it will go because its running multiple coroutines.. you have no code that says already in progress.

Comment: mmh, I understand your reasoning... so how could I solve it? @BugFinder

Comment: have a boolean that says im in motion, if in motion you cant start it again?

Comment: let's say that the approach was already wrong, I was just testing, since I use them the time to calculate while instead I should use a position, calculate a position to reach, but how? @BugFinder

Answer (score 0):

The parameter values for lerp need to be cached beforehand.
This ensures that lerp is using the same parameters for each iteration.
If the first parameter `a` is not fixed, then the lerp changes each iteration.

Definition of Vector3.Lerp

> Interpolates between the points a and b by the interpolant t

ex. when `a` is not fixed:

```
Lerp(0, 10, t)
Lerp(1, 10, t)
Lerp(2, 10, t)
Lerp(3, 10, t)
..
```

Its pretty obvious that these will produce different values for the same value of t.

If we store our start value, then lerp will use the same values for each iteration and will interpolate correctly.
I updated your function to be a bit more concise.

```
private IEnumerator OpenDoor()
{
    var t = 0f;
    var start = transform.eulerAngles;
    var target = open ? openRot : defaulRot;

    while (t < 1)
    {
        gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(start, target, t);

        t += Time.deltaTime / lerpDuration;

        yield return null;
    }  
}
```

If you want to be able to open/close while the routine is already running, you will need to calculate how much time is required to rotate from the current angle to the target angle, and using that calculated time value to get the value of `t`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, in these hours I've been working on the code, I've changed a bit, since I only need to work on the y axis, but the door doesn't open, I don't understand why.

using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorsWithoutKey : MonoBehaviour
{
public bool open = false;

```
[Header("New float")]
[SerializeField] private float openY;

Vector3 currentRot;
public AudioSource UnlockOrLock;
public AudioClip[] DoorSounds;

private void Awake()
{
    UnlockOrLock = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

public void Toggle()
{
    open = !open;
    StopAllCoroutines();

    if (open)
    {
        StartCoroutine(OpenRoutine());
    }
    else
    {
        StartCoroutine(CloseRoutine());
    }
    Unlocked();
}

IEnumerator OpenRoutine()
{
    var rot = gameObject.transform.eulerAngles;

    var currentY = gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y;

    while (currentY < openY)
    {
        currentY = Mathf.Lerp(rot.x, openY, 0.05f);

        var newRot = Quaternion.Euler(rot.x, currentY, rot.z);
        yield return null;
    }    
}

IEnumerator CloseRoutine()
{
    var currentY = transform.localEulerAngles.y;

    var rot = transform.localRotation;

    while (currentY < openY)
    {
        currentY = Mathf.Lerp(currentY, openY, 0.05f);

        var newRot = Quaternion.Euler(rot.x, currentY, rot.z);
        yield return null;
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please update your question with additional information.  Since the above is not an answer to your question, it should not be added as an answer.  Use the edit button on your original question to add these additional details.